# Why do I get an ImportError even if the requirement is already satisfied?

Tags: python, pip

I am making a JARVIS AI for my UBUNTU 20.4.3 . I'd installed pyttsx3 but still I am getting an error. Please help in this:

```
macos@UBUNTU20:~/Python$ python -u "/home/macos/Python/jarvis.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/macos/Python/jarvis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyttsx3
ImportError: No module named pyttsx3
```

```
macos@UBUNTU20:~/Python$ pip install pyttsx3
Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in /home/macos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.90)
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `python --version`?

Comment: Might be a problem with your python/pip version. Try the command @enzo specified. Also try to upgrade your pip packages using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: can you try python3 -u "your script"?

Comment: Try `python3 -u "/home/macos/Python/jarvis.py"` - it looks like it's installed in Python3 but on Ubuntu python is usually the executable name for python2

Comment: `python -m pip install pyttsx3` should use the same pip for that python. If that works find out why it didn't work: `which pip` and `which python`. I think one of them is from local installation: `/usr/local/bin`, mostly Python 3.

Comment: can you post your code same how you are calling the imports?

Comment: Try ```pip3 install pyttsx3```, and if you run ```pip3 freeze | grep pyttsx3``` you should see something, otherwise it means it's not installed

Answer (score 0):

On many Mac/Linux computers (in this case Ubuntu), there is a Python 2 distribution installed. If `python --version` prints something like

```
Python 2.7.9
```

You can solve the confusion by running `python3` instead of `python`:

```
python3 -u "/home/macos/Python/jarvis.py"
```